# How do I attach a texture to JSON object in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

How do I attach a texture to JSON object in Three.js?
Someone help me. Please see my inability cord below.

```
var texture  = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('panel.png');   
texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.set( 1, 1 );

var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( 'panel.json', function ( geometry ) {
    model = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {map: texture} ) );
    scene.add( model )
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below codes, define the material in your json file.

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( 'panel.json', function ( geometry, material ) {
        model = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
        scene.add( model )
    }, 'panel.png');
```

Comment: Hi, user4814065.
Thanks for your reply! but it didn't work very much...
The Json's object was appeared coloring without texture.
I don't know why,It colors ware changed by every reloading.

Comment: ping me the json file

Comment: Do you have set UVs in Json?

Comment: Here's my JSON file by Blender.  No UVs...
[link](http://vanrai.com/ftp/panel.json)

Comment: add materials in Json file